# SQL Server procedure with parameters for table name, field name, and ID of the record

Tags: sql-server

I am trying this in SQL Server and it throws an error:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_TEXT_DETAIL]
    @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @table VARCHAR(255),
    @field VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200)
    SET @sql = 'select ' + QUOTENAME(@field) + ' from ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ' where ID = ' + QUOTENAME(@id)
    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'CFC2776A-6EE1-E511-A172-005056A218B0'.

Is there any way to do this so I don't have to make a bunch or procedures to pull text from a bunch of different tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_TEXT_DETAIL]
(
    @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @table SYSNAME,
    @field SYSNAME
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = '
        SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@field) + '
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + '
        WHERE ID = ''' + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(36)) + ''''

    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

END
```

Comment: may as well use varchar(36)

Answer (score 4):

`QUOTENAME` has optional second parameter *quote char*, so you were close and this could be solved by:

```
... QUOTENAME(@id, '''')
```

but the most proper way for this case is passing the parameter:

```
set @cmd = '
    SELECT t.' + QUOTENAME(@field) + '
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ' t
    WHERE t.ID = @ID'

exec sp_executesql @cmd, N'@ID uniqueidentifier', @ID
```

And server will be able to reuse plan as @srutzsky mentioned. Because @ID is no longer part of a query text and @cmd text remains the same for different @ID (and same @table+@field).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it will scale / perform much better than concatenating the GUID value into the Dynamic SQL string. This approach will at least allow for re-using the plan for the same `@table` + `@field` combination. Concatenating the `@ID` value in will force a new plan for all combinations of `@table` + `@field` + `@ID` which is bad for the plan cache.